# Java Permissions Swing

Tags: java, swing, permissions

My issue is simply that the commented line in `TestMethods#newGame()`, or `button[2][2].setBackground(Color.red);`, will not work, saying that it cannot be resolved to a variable. Where and how would I write the `JButton`, `JPanel`, etc. declaration lines at the top to make it so that the commented line would work? I know it probably has something to do with permissions, but how cold I make it work? By the way, I know that the code is extremely inefficient.
Thank you for all replies, and here is my entire code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements ActionListener
{
    public JButton[][] button = new JButton[8][8];
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public JPanel[][] square = new JPanel[8][8];
    Test() throws IOException
    {
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,8));

        for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
            {
                square[x][y] = new JPanel();
                frame.add(square[x][y]);
                square[x][y].setSize(100,100);
                square[x][y].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                if(y%2==0)
                    if(x%2==0)
                        square[x][y].setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    else
                        square[x][y].setBackground(Color.blue);
                if(y%2!=0)
                    if(x%2==0)
                        square[x][y].setBackground(Color.blue);
                    else
                        square[x][y].setBackground(Color.cyan);
                button[x][y] = new JButton();
                button[x][y] = new TestMethods(x,y);
                square[x][y].add(button[x][y]);
                button[x][y].setOpaque(false);
                button[x][y].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                button[x][y].setBorderPainted(false);
                button[x][y].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }

        frame.setSize(800,900);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        new Test();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object obj = e.getSource();
        TestMethods clicked = (TestMethods)obj;
        int x = clicked.getGridX();
        int y = clicked.getGridY();
        System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
    }
}

class TestMethods extends JButton
{
    private int gridX, gridY;
    public TestMethods(int x, int y)
    {
        this.gridX = x;
        this.gridY = y;
    }

    public int getGridX() {return gridX ;}
    public int getGridY() {return gridY ;}

    public void newGame()
    {
        //button[2][2].setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code has a lot of issues. First thing. The constructor of TestMethods should call super class constructor with a super(). Second. I don't understand these lines button[x][y] = new JButton(); button[x][y] = new TestMethods(x,y);

Comment: Also, in the comment line can you use this.setBackground(Color.red); You are within a specific button that inherits from JButton.

Comment: I don't really know why I put the "new JButton()" line, but could you explain the "super" error I made? The code seems to work besides the commented line. Also, it is an array of JPanels, so how would I specify which JButton to setBackground?

Comment: When you extends a class as a JButton is important in your constructors call to constructor of parent, because in these constructors are initialized some stuff. Then, in your method newGame().. What do you do there?

Comment: @gere: I'm pretty [sure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) "the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code around to show a couple of different ways to get to a button in a panel in a grid. Click the <kbd>New</kbd> button or any grid button to see.

- `TestPanel` overrides `getPreferredSize()`, then you can `pack()` the `frame`.
- A lot of stuff got moved into `TestButton`, including a reference to it's `parent`.
- Each `private static class` can be turned into a package-private `class`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {

    private static final int N = 8;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private TestPanel[][] square = new TestPanel[N][N];
    private TestButton[][] button = new TestButton[N][N];

    public Test() {
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(N, N));
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                TestPanel tp = new TestPanel(x, y);
                square[x][y] = tp;
                button[x][y] = tp.getButton();
                gridPanel.add(tp);
            }
        }
        frame.add(gridPanel);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("New") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button[2][2].newGame();
                square[3][3].setBackground(Color.magenta);
                button[4][4].parent.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
        }));
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final int SIZE = 48;
        private TestButton button;

        public TestButton getButton() {
            return button;
        }

        public TestPanel(int x, int y) {
            super(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            this.button = new TestButton(this, x, y);
            this.add(button);
            if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
                this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            } else {
                this.setBackground(Color.blue);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }

    private static class TestButton extends JButton {

        private TestPanel parent;
        private int gridX, gridY;

        public TestButton(final TestPanel parent, int x, int y) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.gridX = x;
            this.gridY = y;
            this.setOpaque(false);
            this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            this.setBorderPainted(false);
            this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    TestButton clicked = (TestButton) e.getSource();
                    parent.setBackground(Color.green);
                    int x = clicked.getGridX();
                    int y = clicked.getGridY();
                    System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
                }
            });
        }

        public int getGridX() {
            return gridX;
        }

        public int getGridY() {
            return gridY;
        }

        public void newGame() {
            parent.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```